# Is there a way to obfuscate data on the fly via a view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, obfuscation

I have data that is not obfuscated in the table. I need to give query access to certain users via a view but I'd like to know if there is a way to have the data obfuscated when the view is executed? Is this possible in SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Can the table columns with sensitive data simply be omitted from the VIEW?
If not, what are the requirements? For example, can the sensitive data be replaced with constants like 0 for INT, NULL or empty string for VARCHAR, etc.

Comment: replacing the sensitive data is exactly what I'd like to be able to do.